# How to set connection timeout for Mongodb using pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I tried setting `connectTimeoutMS` and `socketTimeoutMS` to a low value but it still takes about 20 seconds before my script times out. Am I not using the options correctly? I want the script to exit after 5 seconds.

```
def init_mongo():
    mongo_connection = MongoClient('%s' %MONGO_SERVER, connectTimeoutMS=5000, socketTimeoutMS=5000)
    if mongo_connection is None:
        return

    try:
        <code>
    except:
        <code>
```

Answer (score 43):

So if anyone comes across this later, I was using the wrong option.

What I was looking for is `serverSelectionTimeoutMS`

Comment: Thank you!  I was having exactly the same problem and could get no change in timeout using the other timeout options.  This worked perfectly!

Comment: I'm getting same issue, could you help me

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No replica set members found yet`

Answer (score 4):

The web page:
https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html
says:

> connectTimeoutMS: (integer or None) Controls how long (in milliseconds) the driver will wait during server monitoring when connecting a new socket to a server before concluding the server is unavailable. Defaults to 20000 (20 seconds)

(Where "server monitoring" is undefined)

So what?  Is connectTimeoutMS sort of like a decoy to keep out the amateurs (like me)