# Set a timeout for a MongoDB request

Tags: python, android, mongodb, pymongo

I am building an android app, with a Backend in python that uses MongoDB.

I am currently trying the handle the case where the ip is not added to MongoDB - meaning the server cant access it.

So I used `try` and `except` on all the MongoDB request, for example:

```
    try:
        matching_locations_list = list(location_collection.find({"username": username}))
    except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError:
        return ["Problem with connecting to MongoDB"]
```

But, it takes a bit of time, usually around 30 seconds, for MongoDB to throw the following error (which i catch):

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError`

My question is - **Is there a way to set this timeout? So my app does not have to be waiting for around 30 second for the server to return "Problem with DB"**

Tried using the following:

```
# Connection options
connection_options = {
    "connectTimeoutMS": 5000,      # Set the connection timeout value in milliseconds
    "socketTimeoutMS": 5000,       # Set the socket timeout value in milliseconds
}
```

and then:

`client = pymongo.MongoClient(connection_string, **connection_options)`

But it didn't same to make any difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297979/how-to-set-connection-timeout-for-mongodb-using-pymongo

Comment: Indeed! thank you. I approved your suggestion.